# jquery not properly handling the jsonp data from twitter api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

See the below code,I am trying to handle the error which is returned by the twitter api call. Remember Jquery do not handle jsonp datatypes and hence the timeout , the below code will obviously throw an error for a non existent twitter ID. I want to catch that error in my req.error method and show it to the user. But apparently , the error is hidden and does come to console.log('Oh noes!'+msg.error); This has surely something to do with the jquery handling jsonp type data. Has anyone encountered the same ? Any solutions ?

```
  function findUserInfo(){


    var req = $.ajax({

    url: "https://twitter.com/users/show.json?id=neverexistID",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    timeout : 10000

    });

    req.success(function(msg) {
        console.log('Yes! Success!'+msg);

    });

    req.error(function(msg) {
        console.log('Oh noes!'+msg.error);
    });


            }
```

Answer:
jsonp calls are special and the errors thrown is usually hidden,and thats why I couldn't handle the error situation,the below plugin handles the situation well and solved my issue.

[jsonp plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp)code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp

Comment: JQuery doesnt seem to handle this , and I have used a jsonp plugin to solve my "error hiding" issue here is the plugin link http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround for your problem, change your url call to:

```
url: "https://twitter.com/users/show.json?suppress_response_codes&id=neverexistID",
```

From the Twitter [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/things-every-developer-should-know#parameters-have-certain-expectations)

> **suppress_response_codes**: If this parameter is present, all responses
>   will be returned with a 200 OK status code - even errors. This
>   parameter exists to accommodate Flash and JavaScript applications
>   running in browsers that intercept all non-200 responses. If used,
>   it’s then the job of the client to determine error states by parsing
>   the response body. Use with caution, as those error messages may
>   change.